# Correct way to set non-displayed database field in APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I'm confused on when to use Dynamic Actions, Computations, and Processes in APEX.

Let's say I have a **PERSON** table with the following fields:
- NUM_ID (non-displayed key, like a GUID)
- CHAR_ID (unique, displayed and enterable)
- NAME

The PERSON table is joined to an **EMPLOYEE** table by the NUM_ID field. The Employee table has the following fields:
- NUM_ID (non-displayed key)
- HIRE_DATE (displayed and enterable)

I have an APEX Form based on the EMPLOYEE table.  I have 2 functions I would like it to perform:

1. When an existing record is ***displayed***, the Form should display the CHAR_ID and NAME for the NUM_ID in that record.
2. When a new record is ***created***, the CHAR_ID is entered.  The Form should retrieve/select the NAME and NUM_ID from the PERSON record, display the person's NAME, and set the non-displayed NUM_ID, so the field is set when the EMPLOYEE record is saved/created.

Is it appropriate to use Dynamic Actions for each of these 2 tasks?

For example, I would have a:

- **GET_CHAR_ID_AND_NAME** Dynamic Action that is executed when the NUM_ID changes (when records are queried)  and
- **GET_NUM_ID_AND_NAME** Dynamic Action that is executed when the CHAR_ID field is changed (on inserts).

The GET_CHAR_ID_AND_NAME Dynamic Action would have Suppress Change Event set to Yes, so it wouldn't trigger the GET_NUM_ID_AND_NAME Dynamic Action, causing a loop.

I worked with APEX years ago, but am forgetting how I used to perform these types of functions.  I think I may be trying to use Dynamic Actions incorrectly and some of this functionality is built into Page Processing?

Any general advice or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, the simplest way to do such things is to (use the Wizard and) create a **report with form on table** as it will create

- an interactive report (IR) you use to view existing data; it lets you navigate to details (i.e. a *form*) and contains the CREATE button to create new records
- a form which is called from the IR and is used to

  - enter new values
  - update or delete existing rows

You don't have to code anything; by default, it'll work. Won't look very pretty, but - it'll work. Apex will create appropriate processes (automatic row fetch & processing). The main "drawback" is that you'll see IDs and not values that stand behind those IDs.

Now, we're on your question: how to "use" (set) an ID, but "display" its description?

I prefer the **Select List** item type to do that. Its source can be (among several options) a SQL query which has to return two values: display (that would be the "name" or "description") and return (that would be the "ID"). For example:

```
select p.name     disp_value,
       e.num_id   ret_value
from person p join employee e on e.num_id = p.num_id
order by p.name
```

Basically, you don't have to code anything, nor create your own functions to do *something* - Apex will do that for you.

I suggest you give it a try and see how it works. As you already used Apex, maybe a little bit of typing (and reading what I've said) will bring the memories back.

Comment: This was a very helpful and is the approach I am taking.  I've created an Interactive Report with a Form. The IR works great, because my select statement joins the 2 tables and displays the name and id.
I'm having trouble with the Form.  I tried using a Select List, but there are over 300,000 records in the table, so that isn't viable. So now I'm experimenting with Validations and Dynamic Actions.  Haven't gotten it working yet.  Running into different issues, depending on what I try.  Guess I need to slow down and record the issues and field property settings of each attempt. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. As of a select list: yes, that's toi much for it, but shouldn't be for a **pop up LoV** - try it.

Comment: Yes I will.  That sounds perfect.  Thanks again.

Comment: No problem :) I hope you'll be able to solve the problem.

Comment: I ended up installing the Skillbuilders Super LOV plug-in. My application works great, with no additional dynamic actions, computations or validations needed. Thank you for your guidance!

Comment: That's fine. Just pay attention to possible Apex upgrades and whether plug-in will work in new Apex version. Because, if it won't you'll be in a trouble.